# useDrag method of react-dnd , cannot get isDragging in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

I am new to `react` with `typescript`, I am implementing drag and drop feature using `react-dnd` package with `typescript`.
following this [blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-drag-and-drop/) I am trying to drag images but I am facing an issue

Property `isDragging` does not exist on type `unknown`

code :

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
        // item denotes the element type, unique identifier (id) and the index (position)
        item: { type, id: image.id, index },
        // collect method is like an event listener, it monitors whether the element is dragged and expose that information
        collect: monitor => ({
          isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        })
      });
```

the error I got : -
[image]

I am confused in the setting type of `isDragging` or how can I solve this error

Comment: Your screenshot seems to indicate that you have 2 errors. What's the error in the parameter for useDrag? Also, I'd suggest checking the official documentation instead of that guide: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drag

Comment: Property 'isDragging' does not exist on type 'unknown'
is error in argument

in docs i cannot find reference for typescript, and i am new to react with typescript

Comment: Needs to add `type` property. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from react-dnd TSX example

[sandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_hooks_ts/04-sortable/simple?from-embed=&file=/src/Container.tsx)

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
        type: "image",
        item: () => {
          return { id, index }
        },
        collect: (monitor: any) => ({
          isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        }),
      })
```

the type is not optional , we need to define type for same

Answer (score 2):

try to add this to you collect function

```
(monitor: DragSourceMonitor)
```

and of course you need to import this interface first

```
import { DragSourceMonitor } from 'react-dnd'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).